# InvalidPipeArgument for pipe 'DatePipe'

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I need to format a date in an angular application so I use the Date Pipe:

```
{{myDate | date:'dd.MM.y'}}
```

The date which I get from a webservice it comes in the following format: **dd/mm/yyyy** (ex.: 31/12/2017). So when I try apply the pipe to a date like 01/01/2017 it works, but not with 31/12/2017, getting the following error: "InvalidPipeArgument: '31/12/2017' for pipe 'DatePipe'"

How can I solve this?

Comment: u r sending input as dd/mm but its expecting mm/dd..not a good approach, but try converting and then sending to pipe..OR maybe new Date(myDate) will work

Comment: For best results, `date` should be either in the form of milliseconds, or a `Date` object, or a standard ISO-8601 date in the form `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.sssZ` (or offset of the form `+hh:mm` instead of `Z`).

Answer (score -1):

Just try with out date pipe or you can create a custom pipe using below method

```
<div>{{convertDate(dateString)}}</div>
```

In your component:

```
convertDate(date){
  let dateArray=date.split("/");
  let newDate = dateArray[0] + "." + dateArray[1] + "." + dateArray[2];
  return newDate;
}
```

Comment: Creating a custom pipe would be better.